# Child windows on System Settings have become transparent

Tags: intel-graphics, settings, window, 14.10

For some reason the sub-windows from the System Settings have corrupted.  By this I mean the backgrounds, which were white, have now become transparent.  While jumping in and out of these child windows I noticed that the online accounts window had none of the accounts I had linked showing.  When I went to add an account, the window showed all the account icons as unavailable (you know, the ghostbusters crossed out ring), and then says 'gnome would like to share...' rather than Ubuntu.

I haven't tried adding gnome to this install.

I am using an Aspire V3-571 with an Intel Core i3 and Intel HD Graphics 3000. Just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10.  Last thing I installed prior to noticing these effects was pulseaudio, but that may be a red herring.

Any help appreciated.

I tried adding a screen grab but this is my first time on here so my rep is to low.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop
```

if this is not working use

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-settings-daemon
```

and
after that

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-settings-daemon
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This solved my problem with the Ubuntu settings windows

Answer (score -1):

You can execute this command in Terminal (use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to launch Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-settings-daemon
```